# where am i going wrong with my rolling banner code to get it scrolling correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering could any one help me with my rolling banner. the problem i am having is that when it loads up on the screen it only moves threw one pic. the code i am using is measured to fit across the top of my page just over the nav bar.

```js
$(function () {

    //settings for slider
    var width = 1165;
    var animationSpeed = 2000;
    var pause = 1000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    //cache DOM elements
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
    var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

    var interval;

    function startSlider() {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            $slideContainer.animate({
                'margin-left': '-=' + width
            }, animationSpeed, function () {
                if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                }
            });
        }, pause);
    }

    function pauseSlider() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    $slideContainer.on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
        .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

    startSlider();


});
```

```css
#slider {
    width: 1165px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width: 1165px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#slider .slide {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 1165px;
    height: 100px;
}
.slide1 {
    background: red;
}
.slide2 {
    background: blue;
}
.slide3 {
    background: green;
}
.slide4 {
    background: purple;
}
.slide5 {
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Container">
    <div id="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide slide1">slide1</li>
            <li class="slide slide2">slide2</li>
            <li class="slide slide3">slide3</li>
            <li class="slide slide4">slide4</li>
            <li class="slide slide5">slide5</li>
            <li class="slide slide1">slide1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

i think my problem is with my measurements i don't fully understand it, to know what to change???? the pictures i am using are width 2192px * height 220px, that might explain were i am getting my measurements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine I think. The actual problem is that your `li` elements are stacked vertically, because they are all `float`ed and floats line-wrap when they get too big for their parent.

Instead of floating them all, you can try using `display: inline-block;` on each `.slide`, and `white-space: nowrap;` on the `.slides`

Here is an example, the only changes from your original are CSS:

```js
$(function () {

    //settings for slider
    var width = 1165;
    var animationSpeed = 2000;
    var pause = 1000;
    var currentSlide = 1;

    //cache DOM elements
    var $slider = $('#slider');
    var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
    var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);

    var interval;

    function startSlider() {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            $slideContainer.animate({
                'margin-left': '-=' + width
            }, animationSpeed, function () {
                if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                }
            });
        }, pause);
    }

    function pauseSlider() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    $slideContainer.on('mouseenter', pauseSlider)
        .on('mouseleave', startSlider);

    startSlider();


});
```

```css
#slider {
    width: 1165px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width: 1165px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0em;
}
#slider .slide {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 1165px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.slide1 {
    background: red;
}
.slide2 {
    background: blue;
}
.slide3 {
    background: green;
}
.slide4 {
    background: purple;
}
.slide5 {
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Container">
    <div id="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide slide1">slide1</li>
            <li class="slide slide2">slide2</li>
            <li class="slide slide3">slide3</li>
            <li class="slide slide4">slide4</li>
            <li class="slide slide5">slide5</li>
            <li class="slide slide1">slide1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much @CodingWithSpike i knew it was something small i just could not spot it.